# Convert images when extention is not in the filename using ImageMagick

Tags: linux, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I would like to convert a jpg image to a pdf file using ImageMagick convert. I can successfully do so using the following:

```
convert image.jpg image.pdf
```

How could I convert the image if the original file name was "image" and not "image.jpg", and the target file name is "image" and not "image.pdf"?

Comment: You may need to use a temp file in between: `convert image image.pdf && mv image.pdf image`.

Comment: @fedorqui  Thought so.  Can it be done in one line?  Do you know if convert requires the input image to have an extension?

Comment: I have never used `convert`, I would suggest to check `man convert`. However, in UNIX environments the extension is something merely informative, so it shouldn't bother. Regarding the line, yes, you can do it one line: having `&&` before `mv` makes the second command execute just if the first was successful.

Comment: @fedorqui.  Tested, and you are correct in that the extention is not needed for the original file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Explicit Image Format](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#input) to force `convert` to use a specific format, regardless of filename.

```sh
convert jpg:image_source pdf:image_out
```